# Python plots - I fixed this code, but need someone to explain how it worked in the first place

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following python code:

```
def graph(seconds,now, dayold, threedayold,weekold):
    x = np.arange(len(seconds))
    ynow = np.array(now)
    yday = np.array(dayold)
    y3day = np.array(threedayold)
    yweek = np.array(weekold)
    # y2 should go on top, so shift them up
    plt.plot(x,ynow)
    plt.plot(x,yday)
    plt.plot(x,y3day,'purple')
    plt.plot(x,yweek)
    plt.fill_between(x,ynow,yday,color='lightblue')
    plt.fill_between(x,yday,y3day,color='green')
    plt.fill_between(x,y3day,yweek,color='purple')
    plt.fill_between(x,yweek,0,color='red')
    plt.show()
```

which produces this graph:

[image]

However, 'seconds' is a list of non-continues results and what I really want is:

```
def graph(seconds,now, dayold, threedayold,weekold):
    x = np.array(seconds)
    ynow = np.array(now)
    yday = np.array(dayold)
    y3day = np.array(threedayold)
    yweek = np.array(weekold)
    # y2 should go on top, so shift them up
    plt.plot(x,ynow)
    plt.plot(x,yday)
    plt.plot(x,y3day,'purple')
    plt.plot(x,yweek)
    plt.fill_between(x,ynow,yday,color='lightblue')
    plt.fill_between(x,yday,y3day,color='green')
    plt.fill_between(x,y3day,yweek,color='purple')
    plt.fill_between(x,yweek,0,color='red')
    plt.show()
```

So that I could get a proper X-Y plot.  However when I try the second bit of code I get this error:

```
josephs-mbp-3$Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp.py", line 47, in <module>
    graph(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4])
  File "./temp.py", line 41, in graph
    plt.fill_between(x,yweek,0,color='red')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2287, in fill_between
    ret = ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 6489, in fill_between
    y2 = np.ones_like(x)*y2
NotImplementedError: Not implemented for this type
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this and how I fix it?

EDIT: Ah-ha!  I fixed it, but would like someone to tell me how...

Changing

```
 plt.fill_between(x,yweek,0,color='red')
```

to

```
plt.fill_between(x,yweek,[0]* len(seconds),color='red')
```

produced what I wanted - and I can understand why this would be a problem,  but I'm confused as to why the first version worked at all... any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code that is relevant to your Exception? Should be around line 41.

Answer (score 1):

I think that seconds is probably a list of number strings, perhaps loaded from a file, rather than a list of numeric types.

The fill_between function of matplotlib expects an array of numeric type as an argument or else it crashes. This is a bit confusing since the plot function seems to do a cast from string to float when you call it.

So I think doing something like:

```
x = [float(i) for i in seconds]
```

rather than:

```
x = np.array(seconds)
```

should solve your problem!